# Force NuGet to delete package content files before a new update

Tags: reference, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

I am forced to use an asp.net project wrapped up in a NuGet package. I am very aware that this is not what's NuGet for and it isn't the best solution, but as I said I am forced to be using it.

Since whenever the project files are deleted or renamed from the NuGet project, and I update the main project that is referencing the NuGet project, NuGet wouldn't delete previously installed files that are now changed, my question is:

*Is there a way to force NuGet to delete the files from the previous version, before installing a new one?*